# Is "stabilise society" without an article acceptable usage?

Tags: articles, zero-article

> Zeman, who paid a four-day state visit to China on October 24-27, has told Chinese Television that he did not go to China to teach lessons on human rights but, on the contrary, to learn ways to **stabilise society**.
>
> <sub>[Source](http://www.ceskenoviny.cz/zpravy/prague-to-further-speak-about-human-rights-with-china-formin/1141724)</sub>

Is the absence of the definite article before the word "society" OK?

Comment: Yes. It's fine. It's standard, in fact...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfect. You could even argue that if it *did* have a definite article it would become less clear. As Catija mentioned, it is a standard construction.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds perfect. Having any article before the word would change the meaning entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Society here is representing the unified idea of a non-specific referral to any society you know - all societies (plural, needs no article) and yet also refers to none in particular. . (needs no "the" speficic article).

Answer (score -1):

I think an article is warranted in this instance, especially since the word "society" is singular. The statement above would be similar to

> The med student learned to save patient.
> Correct usages would be
> The med student learned to save **a** patient ... (say by performing a procedure)
>
> The med student learned to save patient**S** ... (by ...)
>
> The med student saved **the** patient.

The statement without an article does not sound right.